# Persistent LED when is MOSFET off

Tags: mosfet

I am testing for a larger circuit, and as such am checking if a MOSFET can be controlled via PWM. I used the test circuit below. PWM and 5V supply are provided using an Analogue Discovery 2.

Using the 5V PWM signal I can vary the light intensity between nothing and maximum. When I turn the PWM signal off entirely (even if setting it to 0% duty cycle beforehand, which extiguishes the LED) the LED lights at a level lower than the maximum, which is seemingly the same as if I apply a DC 5V signal instead of the PWM when the circuit is 'active'.

Any advice on why this happens and if it can be mitigated?

[image]

Comment: The cautious don't take chances on leaving a MOSFET gate floating: connect a 33k-ish resistor from there to source or ground. No idea why the current/brightness wouldn't change with duty cycle: Does or doesn't it?

Comment: no current limiting resistor for the LED?

Comment: On top of above comments, why high side MOSFET instead of standard low side?

Comment: @greybeard The brightness did change with the duty cycle, but when disabling that PWM signal in software the light would return to a low level of lit.

Comment: @user253751 I tried using a 220Ohm resistor in series, but found that it limited the light output of the LED a great deal.

Comment: @winny I was not aware that there is a significant difference in operation? I can give it a try.

Comment: @DanielGodø-Dempsey You are using the MOSFET in common-drain mode so the voltage is limited to about 3.3V (that's the 5V gate voltage minus about 1.7V threshold voltage) depending on the specific type of MOSFET used whereas if you swap the position of the MOSFET and LED it is common-source mode and the LED can get the full 5 volts (and then probably needs a resistor)

Comment: (I can see that some super-duper-cost-conscious engineer might intentionally (and carefully) do it this way to save on a resistor but if that isn't you then just do it the same way everyone else does because it's more reliable. Your way does run the risk the LED brightness could change quite a lot if the 5V changes only a little bit)

Comment: @user253751 That makes sense, though earlier testing of the actual 12V LED to be used later showed a lot of dimming when limited by a resistor. I suppose that it depends entirely on the LED whether it tolerates non-current-limited operation?

Comment: MOSFETs come with a wide variety of gate threshold voltages.  Some of them are TTL logic compatible and obviously it make some sense to look for one of those.

Comment: @DanielGodø-Dempsey Please simulate both. You have a source follower.

Comment: @user107063 So as to check if the MOSFET works as a switch?

Comment: @winny I have rebuilt the circuit as both (with current limiting resistor and 33k pull-down on gate) and the high-side setup results in no lighting when off, but the low-side does.

Comment: *[even with gate-source resistor] the low-side setup results in lighting when off* Please put that and a schematic in a question post if you want that answered.

Comment: Please show with a schematic. Measure Vgs and Vds when off.

Answer (score 1):

When you unplug (or cut off) the PWM signal, there is no defined output voltage.

So the gate of your mosfet is floating (ie it can't be at any voltage). In that situation, you might get any behaviour, depending on the gate voltage you get by "parasistic" elements (the last charge of the parasitic gate capacitance, leakage, electro-static discharges, antena behaviour of the wires, ...).

In other words, if the gate of a mosfet is unconnected, the result can be anything (on, off, in between (that might destroy our mosfet because it allows current to flow through the mosfet while it is in "high resistance" mode, so it might overheat). You can't even rely on the fact that the behaviour will always be the same. Maybe if you try again in an hour, the mosfet will be off. Or if you touch the gate with your fingers, or with the voltmeter.

The normal procedure for a mosfet gate that might not be driven at some point if, as greybeard suggested, to add a pullup or pulldown resistor (some quite high resistor value, depending on the circuit it is usually between 10k and 1M) to either GND or the positive supply, depending on the default behaviour you which for (if you wish the default to be like 0% PWM, then use a pulldown to ground, if you wish default to be like 100% PWM, then use a pullup to 5V).

So to hotfix the issue, just add the resistor.

And as user253751 suggested, you probably want to add a current limiting resistor in series with your led (either between LED and GND, or between LED and Mosfet) : most LEDs don't support 5V for long (nb : there ae some special LEDs with integrated resistor : if you get one (ie if it is rated for 5V) then you are fine)

Comment: I changed the MOSFET to low-side and added both a 33k pulldown resistor and a 220Ohm current limiting resistor, but the partial lighting of the LED seems to still be present.

Comment: @DanielGodø-Dempsey You haven't provided a schematic but try replacing your MOSFET if it has developed a leak. Unlikely, but MOSFETs are cheap.